# How to auto calculate edittext inside listview in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I have a ListView with edittext in each items and I want to know how can when i change value of edittext , Text result will be change . Please give me some example

Comment: can you share your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
holder.mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
// use s.toString() vaue .
}
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,int count, int after) {
                }
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,int before, int count) {
                }
            });
```

Comment: i could not understand this " how can when i change value of edittext , Text result will be change . Please give me some example" please elaborate what you want.